# How to get last row + column from a collection in C# using lambda

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IEnumerable` object which has 3 fields.

Fields `A`, `B` and `ResultNumber`.

How do I get only the `Resultnumber` from the last row using lambda expression?

I tried the following which didn't work:

```
resultnum = result.LastOrDefault(d => d.ResultNumber)
```

In this case I already have results which are stored in the resultnum variable.

Comment: What didn't work? What exception did you get?

Comment: You can supply a Predicate function to LastOrDefault(), not a selector.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the last row and *then* the `ResultNumber`:

```
var lastResultNumber = result.Last().ResultNumber;
```

Or if there may be no rows:

```
var lastOrDefault = result.LastOrDefault();
if (lastOrDefault != null)
{
    var lastResultNumber = lastOrDefault.ResultNumber;
}
else
{
    // Handle the case with no rows
}
```

The overloads for `Last()`, `LastOrDefault()` etc which take a delegate use that delegate for filtering - so this:

```
var query = foo.Last(predicate);
```

is broadly equivalent to:

```
var query = foo.Where(predicate).Last();
```

That's not what you're trying to achieve in this case.

Answer (score 1):

you want something like this:

```
if ( someCollection != null && someCollection.Count > 0 )
    result = somecollection.Last().ResultNumber
```